# How can we apply shell commands by using puppet providers?

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, puppet

I have my custom puppet provider with property of ensure as below.

```
....
def create 
     /* echo 'show system uptime' >> /home/Vinoth/config_vino.txt */
end

def destroy
     FileUtils.rm_rf '/home/Vinoth/config_vino.txt'
end

def exists?
     File.file? 'config_vino.txt'
end
```

In the manifest `ensure = 'present'`. So when the the file `config_vino.txt` does not exist, I want to create it by using shell command `echo`. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this? Hope my question is clear and if not please come back.

My aim is to execute shell commands using puppet providers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, there are some ways to execute a shell command. What you actually want to do, though, is the equivalent of this (untested):

```
def create
  uptime = `your uptime command`
  Puppet::FileSystem.open(filename, nil, 'w') do |file|
    file.write("#{uptime}\n")
  end
end
```